# 2D Electron Gas interface of two semiconductors

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics

I am looking at a book or paper describing the theoretical description of a 2D electron gas formed at the interface of two semiconductors. I have encountered many experimental realisations of 2D electron gas, but I want a theoretical paper if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many papers, conference proceedings and books on this topics. Keyword: two-dimensional electronic systems. Maybe you'll find what you are looking for in this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9810232799). The following is a book by the Nobel prize winner [Dan Tsui](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IKVVR9Y) (Princeton University).